# Adding CURE clustering algorithm to WEKA

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, data-mining

I have written a java program to perform CURE clustering.
I wish to add this program to weka as a clustering algorithm and visualize the clustering.
Has anyone already implemented it on weka?Any links to that would be very much helpful.
How do I proceed with it?

Comment: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/package-summary.html - This is the JavaDoc for the clustering functionality in WEKA. This seems to me a good place to start reading if you wish to implement new clusterer in WEKA. Also check the corresponding source codes.

Answer (score 3):

Weka is *very* weak on clustering. Actually clustering in Weka is pretty much non-existant. The implementations of e.g. OPTICS are essentially external programs that are just called, but not at all integrated.
You might want to have a look at ELKI, http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/ which is like Weka for clustering and outlier detection (it doesn't have classification though - this is where Weka is strong). It does not yet have CURE though, either. But a dozen of other clusterers and visualizations for them.

Answer (score 2):

There is a CURE on Weka project available here:
[http://code.google.com/p/data-mining-cure-algorithm](http://code.google.com/p/data-mining-cure-algorithm/)